# Error while setting state in React Native Picker onValueChange

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've found this issue recently while working with `Picker`. I want my `Picker` has a placeholder like the one in `TextInput`. So I came up with the idea that add another "fake" item in `Picker`. Here is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Button, TextInput, View, Picker } from 'react-native';
import { Formik } from 'formik';

export default class MyReactNativeForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      fakeItem: true
    }
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <Formik
      initialValues={{ email: '', item:'' }}
      onSubmit={values => console.log(values)}
    >
      {props => (
        <View>
          <TextInput
            onChangeText={props.handleChange('email')}
            onBlur={props.handleBlur('email')}
            value={props.values.email}
          />
          <Picker selectedValue= {props.values.item} onValueChange={itemValue => {
               if(itemValue !== -1) {props.setFieldValue('item',itemValue);}
               this.setState({fakeItem: false});
               console.log(this.state)
          }} >
             {this.state.fakeItem && <Picker.Item label = "-- Select item --" value = {-1}></Picker.Item>}
             //fake item for placeholder
             <Picker.Item label = "First" value = "FirstItem"></Picker.Item>
             <Picker.Item label = "Second" value = "SecondItem"></Picker.Item>
          </Picker>
          <Button onPress={props.handleSubmit} title="Submit" />
        </View>
      )}
    </Formik>
    )
  }

}
```

As you can see above I have a state which determines whether the fake item is displayed or not. My goal is when the component first mounted, the fake item will be shown as placeholder, and when user chooses other item, the fake item will disappear. When the component is mounted everything is fine but when I selected item in `Picker` I got an error:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'child.props')
>   - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\Picker\PickerAndroid.android.js:67:16 in 
>   - node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:1144:30 in mapSingleChildIntoContext

I think the problem is the `setState()` method inside `onValueChange` property of the `Picker` causes this error. Can anyone help me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Do you try removing `{props => (`?

Answer (score 0):

I had run your code and error is coming . Just remove **//fake item for placeholder** and code is working now

[image]

Complete code

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, TextInput, View, Picker } from "react-native";
import { Formik } from "formik";

export default class Home2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fakeItem: true
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ email: "", item: "" }}
        onSubmit={values => console.log(values)}
      >
        {props => (
          <View>
            <Picker
              selectedValue={props.values.item}
              onValueChange={itemValue => {
                if (itemValue !== -1) {
                  props.setFieldValue("item", itemValue);
                }
                this.setState({ fakeItem: false });
                console.log(this.state);
              }}
            >
              {this.state.fakeItem && (
                <Picker.Item label="-- Select item --" value={-1} />
              )}
              <Picker.Item label="First" value="FirstItem" />
              <Picker.Item label="Second" value="SecondItem" />
            </Picker>
            <Button onPress={props.handleSubmit} title="Submit" />
          </View>
        )}
      </Formik>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Definitely I remove that in my code. Do you try to select one of the item? I try to do it and it comes an error. By the way my code is ran on Android .

Comment: You can see in Gif image of running code . I have selected one  item and fakeitem is  removed . Can you try my code?